# How to calc area using OpenLayers with UTM coordinates

Tags: openlayers, area, calculate-values

I just need had a point format like below (zone,x,y) and need to calculate it's `Area`.

> 39,553816,3791942 39,548052,3731376 39,637947,3711980 39,616343,3808591

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a example and it seams to works fine. I used project4 to transform UTM coordinates to EPSG3854(Openlayer default projection)

```
function utm2EPSG3857(point, zone) {
    const utm = "+proj=utm +zone=" + zone;
    const target = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs";
    return proj4(utm, target, point);
}


var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4
    })
});
  
let utmPointString = '39,553816,3791942 39,548052,3731376 39,637947,3711980 39,616343,3808591';

let finalPoints =[...utmPointString.matchAll(/(?<z>\d+),(?<x>[\d\.]+),(?<y>[\d\.]+)\s?/g)].map(m=>utm2EPSG3857([m.groups.x*1,m.groups.y*1],m.groups.z))

var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([finalPoints])
})
console.log(finalPoints);
var area = ol.sphere.getArea(new ol.geom.Polygon([finalPoints]));
alert(area);
```